# Component testing: cypress with vue, vite and vuetify

Tags: vue.js, cypress, vite

I'm trying to run a component testing for my vuejs app.
I configured my cypress server following cypress configuration wizard [Configuring Component Testing](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/vue/quickstart).

**I wanted to run a basic test with just mounting the component :**

```
import ProgressCircular from './ProgressCircular.vue'
describe('<ProgressCircular />', () => {
it('renders', () => {
cy.mount(ProgressCircular)
})
```

})

**I came into this error :**

> [Vuetify] Could not find defaults instance

**My vuetify config :**

```
import 'vuetify/styles'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/lib/util/colors'

const vuetify = createVuetify({
  icons: {
    defaultSet: 'mdi',
    sets: {},
  },
})

export default vuetify
```

**NB**:

My application ran and built successfully.

I'm using:

> vite 4, Vue 3, Vuetify 3,  Cypress 12.5.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a Vue application, you need to register plugins and global components in order for your application to be able to use them, and this also applies when working with Cypress.

Your plugins and global components will probably be registered in "src/main.ts" or something. For Vuetify this will look something like this:

```
import vuetify from "@/plugins/vuetify";
import App from "@/App.vue";
const app = createApp(App);
// Use plugins
app.use(vuetify);
```

To add this to cypress you need to modify the mount command. In the following example the vuetify plugin is added when a component is mounted:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("mount", (component, options = {}) => {
// Setup options object
options.global = options.global || {};
options.global.stubs = options.global.stubs || {};
options.global.stubs["transition"] = false;
options.global.components = options.global.components || {};
options.global.plugins = options.global.plugins || [];

/* Add any global plugins */
options.global.plugins.push({
  install(app) {
    app.use(vuetify); //import vuetify from you vuetify config
  },
});

return mount(component, options);
});
```

Further reading on the mount command: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/mount

I am using cypress v12. By default the settings for the mount command were located in the cypress/support/components.ts

Comment: Thank you so very much! This should be more present on Google, it would have saved me lots of time.

Comment: This works for me, thanks. I just added " import { createApp } from 'vue' " and change "@/plugins/vuetify"; " to " "@/main"; " because my createVuetify() is declared in my main.ts .